# How to know if a server is online or not, if we only know the IP?

Tags: c++, winapi, curl, network-programming

How can that be done, the server is not an HTTP server, its a ArmA game server.
I tried to achieve it using CURL in the following code, but it didn't work, it always show Offline.

```
IsOnline( "xx.xxx.xx.xxx" );

    bool IsOnline( string url )
    {

        CURL *curl;

        curl = curl_easy_init();

        if(curl) 
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str() );


            CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            if ( result != CURLE_OK )
            {
               error_string = curl_easy_strerror( result );
               return false;
            }

            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            curl_global_cleanup();
            return true;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing in your code is trying to send an HTTP request. The reason it fails is because the game server machine isn't running a HTTP server.

The usual way to find out whether a machine is online or not is by [pinging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) it. Ping uses the ICMP protocol. Here is a tutorial explaining how to ping from a C++ program (it's Windows-specific): http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4628/how-to-ping/

However, the admins of the server might have disabled ICMP, in which case the machine won't respond to pings even if it's online. Moreover, you can get "false positives" if the machine is online and responding to pings, but the game server software itself isn't running.

So I think your best bet would be to find out which ports the game server itself listens to and attempt a connection on those ports.